# Unable to publish Classic project Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, publishing

I'm trying to publish a classic project in Appcelerator Titanium. I tried both publishing it with '`Apple Store`' and '`Adoc`' but failed with both.

I get a popup saying successfully published, but when I check the **xCode > Organizer** window I cannot find my Archive file.

I tried the same exercise with a new 'Hello World' project, but the results were no different.

> **Has anyone any idea on how to publish a classic project or**
>   **Appcelerator has stopped publishing the Classic project and just**
>   **supports Alloy project.**

Good Luck and Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. It was the **xCode version** that caused the issue, I had to use 8.1 to get it working. Have a look at the below link which give us the compatibility of Titanium SDK with the xCode :

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode

**GoodLuck Cheers...!**